# Parse and replace string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

i have various strings that look like that:

```
$(gateway.jms.jndi.ic.url,0,tibjmsnaming, tcp)/topic/$(gateway.destination.prefix)$(gateway.StatusTopicName),$(gateway.jms.jndi.ic.username),$(gateway.jms.jndi.ic.password),abinding,tBinding
```

i'm trying to figure out a way to extract the $(...) sections and replace them with some other string.

is there anyway in C# to parse those groups and replace one by one with another string?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression will capture those sections:

> `\$\([^)]+\)`

Then replace like this (this example changes each match to it's uppercase equivalent - you can add whatever custom logic you wish):

```
Regex.Replace(candidate, @"\$\([^)]+\)", delegate(Match m) {
    return m.ToString().ToUpper();
});
```

Comment: Great! what if i want that the matching result will be w/o the '$' or the '(' ')' chars?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not so good with delegate.s Here is what i came up with using Andrew's regex:

```
string test1 = @"$(gateway.jms.jndi.ic.url,0,tibjmsnaming, tcp)/topic/$(gateway.destination.prefix)$(gateway.StatusTopicName),$(gateway.jms.jndi.ic.username),$(gateway.jms.jndi.ic.password),abinding,tBinding";

            string regex1 = @"\$\([^)]+\)";

            var matches = Regex.Matches(test1, regex1);

            Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                test1 = test1.Replace(match.Value, "your String");                  
            }
            Console.WriteLine(test1);
```

Comment: you should directly use Regex.Replace instead of your foreach loop